# Moving a changing file to a new server using Gzip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file in AWS S3 that is updating every second (actually collecting new data). I want to move the collected file to my local server periodically. Here are a few things that I am considering.

1. The transportation needs to be done in a zipped somehow to reduce the network burden since the cost the S3 is based on the network load.
2. After moving the data out of AWS S3, the data on S3 need to be deleted. In another way, the sum of the data on my server and the data on AWS should be the complete dataset and there should be intersection between these two datasets. Otherwise, next time, when we move the data, there will be duplicates for the dataset on my server.
3. The dataset on S3 is collecting all the time, and the new data is appended to the file using standard in. There is something running on the cron job to collect the data.

Here is a pseudo code that shows the idea of how the file has been built on S3.

```
* * * * * nohup python collectData.py >> data.txt
```

Which requires that the data transportation cannot break the pipeline, otherwise, the new data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to mount S3 bucket as local directory (for example, using [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) project) and use standard shell tools (like rm, cp, mv ..) to remove an old file and upload a new file to Amazon S3.